# Check field position in an Excel

Tags: excel

How to check field position in an Excel? I have to check length of an ASCii File and field positions. I have checked the length but not sure how to check the positions of field.

Example I have:

```
Account Number   Len   Institution   Len   Cost Center   Len
830226579        9     268           3     8924          4
830168953        9     268           3     8904          4
830255130        9     268           3     8904          4
830065638        9     268           3     8924          4
830065620        9     268           3     8924          4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I don't understand what you mean by 'field position'. Could you perhaps post some examples if you can?

Comment: Hello Jerry. I have following table for an example,Account Number Len Institution Len Cost Center Len
830226579 9 268 3 8924 4
830168953 9 268 3 8904 4
830255130 9 268 3 8904 4
830065638 9 268 3 8924 4
830065620 9 268 3 8924 4
I have to check the length which i already have gotten but i have to check the field position. So how do i check the field position in this column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. What are you expected to do with this table?

Comment: Nvm i actually figured it out. Thank you Jerry

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the cell boundaries with the Text Import Wizard.